# Three step order form, how to go to next step

Tags: page-template, forms, include

I have an order.php that is in fact a custom page template. This template loads the first step of my order form via:

```
<?php include('order/order-step-one.php'); ?>
```

Now in this order-step-one.php my Next-button (post method) has to send the user to /order/order-step-two.php

Currently this does not work. I need to find a way to include order-step-two in the original order.php via the submit button in order-step-one. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `order.php` you will need something like this:

```
$step = (isset($_POST['step'])) ? $_POST['step'] : 'one';

switch ($step) {
    case 'one':
      // do step one
      break;
    case 'two' :
      // do step two
      break;
    case 'three' :
      // do step three
      break;
}
```

Your form, of course, has to send the appropriate arguments. I used `POST`, which seems most appropriate for this kind of thing, but the same would be true for `GET`.

This makes everything process on your one page which WordPress knows about and that will greatly simplify things.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this. Why do I get Unexpected '=' on line 30? thus after step = (isset...

Comment: Because I have a typo. Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: You are missing `;` on the line endings, for one. Do it just like I did. If you want to change the value substitute `order-step-one` for `one` in my code. But if you are having trouble with PHP syntax you best going to the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).

Comment: Solved it. Thx for your help s_ha_dum :)